# Return doctrine object to array/json by findall() -gives an error - of on object

Tags: arrays, json, symfony

I am getting an error on line 10   :
 Call to a member function getUserId() on a non-object in

```
    /** @var $users User*/
    $users= $this->getRepository("repo")->findAll();
    $response = array();
    foreach ($users $user) {
        $response[] = array(
 **line10           'user_id' => $user->getUserId()

        );
    }
```

basicly in line 10 it did not recognize the call to getUserId 
so how could I fetch the data to array or json ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop on `$campaigns`, one of the elements of the array seem to be `null`, so this element does not have the method `getUserId`. Try to `var_dump` your `$campaigns` array to check its content, I'm pretty sure you would be able to find the mistake after that.

Comment: var dump gives entity object from the db with the correct data

Answer (score 0):

Try:  `$campaigns = $this->getDoctrine->getRepository("repo")->findAll();`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `$campaigns` have no results, try:

```
if($capaigns) {
    foreach ($campaigns as $user) {
        $response[] = array('user_id' => $user->getUserId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Campagins/user contain the entity object and the data is correct , only inside the for there is a problem